# neo4j load csv imports all columns in the first

Tags: csv, neo4j

I've tried to import one csv file into Neo4j using the `LOAD CSV` Cyper Statement. As I saw [here](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/06/load-csv-into-neo4j-quickly-and-successfully/) it might be useful to check the lines. I am using Windows (and I use version Neo4j 2.1) so I have the following query

```
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/Users/Neo4j/Worldcup_2014.csv" AS line 
    WITH line LIMIT 5 RETURN line.world_cup, line.a_score;
```

What I get as result is not was I expected because in world_cup (which is the first column) there is the content of the whole line:

```
    world_cup,id,home,away,h_score,a_score,new_match_number,date,time,stadium,phase,year,host
    "2014 FIFA World Cup Brasiliaâ„¢","3000614541","Brazil","Croatia","3","1","1","12/06/2014","22:00",""Sao Paulo / Sao Paulo"","Group matches","2014","Brazil"
    "2014 FIFA World Cup Brasiliaâ„¢","3000614542","Mexico","Cameroon","1","0","2","13/06/2014","18:00",""Natal / Estádio das Dunas"","Group matches","2014","Brazil"
```

And all the other fields I want to return have the value `null`

I've tried to use the `FIELDSEPARATOR ','` but it has no effect! What may I do to get the right result?

Comment: Perhaps it is an UTF-8 marker problem in your file? Try to remove that marker? You also have some weird characters in there.

Did you use the csv files from the worldcup github repository?

Comment: Make sure that you remove all spaces before before each row. Not sure if that is the case in your file or you indented too many times on your question. A link to your CSV file would be helpful.

Comment: I only opended the file in Excel so everything seemed to be okay, but as I edited the file in an editor I found too many quotation marks. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me, load csv with headers from "file:/Users/lalitazad/Documents/exports/usertable.csv" as csvline with csvline limit 1 create (:user{id:csvline.id});

where in my csv in on the filesystem. And I wanted to create one node in the node4j. Also, you can remove the limit, and you can import all the records

I forgot to add, the csv contains the id as on the of column-names, and I am just creating one node with one field as id;